# Items in details repeating itself in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

### Situation

I got stucked to some weirdo  in Crystal reports. See the image below of my RAW RPT.

[image]

Everything in my report is coming fine except the details part. You can see there DetailsSection6, in which i have few columns(10-15). This rpt is binded with the XSD file and that XSD is then binded with its concerned dataset at runtime. Dataset has around 10 tables from which two tables are concerned here.

1. PROC_CONS_SUBBILL_REPORT - Header Table with single row.
2. CON_T_SUBBILL_DTL - Detail table having multiple rows based on the `VoucherNo` of above table.

### What I want

I need to display all records of detail table in tablular format based upon the `VoucherNo`. Say in detail table (SUBBILL_DTL), I am having 25 records, but when table is rendered on the rpt, its starts repeating itself, sometimes twice sometimes thrice.

### Kindly note:

1. My SP is returning the expected and correct data
2. RPT has 5-6 SubReports and in one report PROC_CONS_SUBBILL_REPORT table is used.
3. There is no Relationships in the report in the form of keys.

### What I did

1. Tried removing all keys between the tables.
2. Suppressed the Detail Section but it suppresses the entire data.
3. Suppress the detail section with formula
   `{CON_T_SUBBILL_REPORT.CODE}=previous( {CON_T_SUBBILL_REPORT.CODE})`
   but still its not working.

I am totally lost. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Normally records are duplicated when the linking is wrong, In your case instead of formula try to use the option `Select Distinct Records` under `Database` tab.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little late, but in case somebody else is looking for an answer.
I tried all the things above and nothing worked. Crystal reports was changing my query.
It worked in SQL Server but not in Crystal Reports.
The way I fixed it was by creating a view of my query on Sql Server and using the view
in my Crystal Report. It fixed everything.